# "list indices must be integers, not tuple" but it worked before?

Tags: python

I have a 2d list of the form:

```
d = [[0.87768026489137663, -0.42848220833223599],
[0.87770426313019434, -0.428411425505765],
[0.87796388044104012, -0.42873867479872063],
[0.87801587662514491, -0.42860583582101786],
[0.87794315468933382, -0.42847396647067809]]
```

I want to get a single column from it, I've done this before on a different program using d[:,0] or d[:,1] and it worked perfectly.  But now when I try that I get the error: list indices must be integers, not tuple.  I know this must be a really simple fix but I'm just not sure whats wrong.  I'm using python 3.4 if that matters.

Comment: @alfasin he wants the column not the row.

Comment: _I've done this before on a different program using `d[:,0]` or `d[:,1]`_ - this looks like numpy, which has its [own syntax for slicing](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html). Did you mean to use numpy here and just forget to include it?

Answer (score 1):

You have a list of lists. What you want to do is iterate through the list of lists, and for every sub-list, pick out the first item if you want the first column, or the second item if you want the second column, etc. The following one-liner will do that:

```
column = [x[0] for x in d]
```

Note that `x[0]` selects the first item in the sub-list. If you want the second item, take `x[1]`, etc. Generally, if you want the `n`th column in your 2d list (call it `d`), the code to grab that column is:

```
column = [x[n] for x in d]
```

Comment: thank you for the quick response, Ive actually figured out the problem already though.  the issue was that I hadn't defined it to be a numpy array, I forgot d[:,0] only works for numpy arrays.  I will keep what you said in mind when working with normal lists

Comment: @Newb Oh sorry you are right, i will delete my comments.

Comment: @Newb Only one issue, this is a inefficient way to get the column `n`, its better using built-in function `zip`.

Comment: @levi I don't know the internal mechanics of Python well enough to say whether this is more or less efficient than using `zip` -- I intuitively assume that `zip` uses iteration as well, but I don't know. However, I think this answer may be better suited to a newcomer, as it is very simple to understand.

Comment: @newb `zip` is a built-in function implemented at lower level, because that is more efficient. Yes, you answer is simple to understand but if you are working with bid data set and matrices, its better to learn how handle it reducing time.

Comment: @levi Interesting! How is `zip` implemented at a lower level than list iteration? Can you give me a reference, please?

Comment: @Newb python built-in function are written directly in `C`, you can emulate `zip` behavior using loops, but the interpreter needs to parse the loop and transform it to lower level code, if you use zip, interpreter would be call the built-in code in C, avoiding extra work.

Answer (score 0):

In python you cant get a column using R notation from a matrix, you can do that using numpy lib. If you want to get the column `i` using pure python, just do:

```
columns   = map(list,zip(d))  
column_i  = columns [i] #i is the column that you want
```

Example

```
d = [[1,2],[3,4] ]
new_d = zip(d)
>> [(1,3),(2,4)]
map(list,new_d)
>> [[1,3],[2,4]]
```

Comment: thank you for the quick response, Ive actually figured out the problem already though. the issue was that I hadn't defined it to be a numpy array, I forgot d[:,0] only works for numpy arrays. I will keep what you said in mind when working with normal lists

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you are going to use the data in the list for further calculations. My favourite for handling such lists is "numpy". If you import the numpy module, you can access the data like you proposed:

```
import numpy as np

d = np.array([[0.87768026489137663, -0.42848220833223599],
              [0.87770426313019434, -0.428411425505765],
              [0.87796388044104012, -0.42873867479872063],
              [0.87801587662514491, -0.42860583582101786],
              [0.87794315468933382, -0.42847396647067809]])

d[:,1]
```

output:

```
array([-0.42848221, -0.42841143, -0.42873867, -0.42860584, -0.42847397])
```

I find it much easier to use numpy for such data as it is more intuitive to use than list comprehensions. 
Hope this helps.

Comment: thank you, I am in fact using numpy and had totally forgotten that I need to convert it to a numpy array before before using that technique!

Comment: just a note: if `d` is `tuple` then you need to change the name: `d1 = np.array(d)`